# How to make a shadow on Semantic Ui React Navbar Menu

Tags: css, reactjs, menu, navbar, shadow

Im trying to make a **shadow on navbar**... I know how to make a shadow but its not working on my navbar.

Here is an image of what my navbar look like...

[image]

I purposely but green border so you can see that i didnt put the wrong class name.

i put a red shadow on the navbar and the box...

Here is my css for navbar:

```
.ui.secondary.pointing.menu {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green !important;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px red !important;
}
```

and here is for the box:

```
.box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px red !important;
}
```

You can see my full code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-darwin-lr55t

And you can preview here:
https://ml88b.csb.app/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your shadow is working but not visible because of `.box` background-color. remove background-color or move the `menu` div inside `pushable` div.

Or

add
`position: relative;`
style to this class `.ui.secondary.pointing.menu`

Comment: can you like edit my sandbox and share me the link
edit: Nvm it did work but how can i make the content? Also if i try to move my menu inside pushable div everything get ruined so thats a no

Comment: are you online?

Comment: add`position: relative;` style to this class `.ui.secondary.pointing.menu`

Comment: yo you actually fixed it. THANKS! enjoy your upvote and checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understood, what was the issue.

```
.ui.secondary.pointing.menu {
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px red !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you i did understand what is the issue... i already tried zindex but its not working. pls help im just beginner

Comment: ill upvote you aswell since you helped me understand what was the error :)
Enjoy your upvote

Answer (score 0):

none of the answer were working for me, so I just add:

`z-index:1` to the equivalent of your `.ui.secondary.pointing.menu` class

so the header and its shadow are pushed forward

and no need of `!important` if you specify enough pointers to you header